# Displaying uploaded files from server in dropzone js

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using the *dropzone js* plugin to upload files to a php server. It is working great. I am facilitating the user to update the uploaded files. So once the user clicks on update button, the dropzone appears, and I am able to display the uploaded files in it through a *JQuery-AJAX* call. But my problem is that though the files are displayed in the thumbnail format, the number of files in the dropzone counts to zero. I feel that the accept function is not being triggered.But if a new file is added to the displaying list the file count is 1 though there are files already existing in it.

I am using the following code to display the files in dropzone:

```
var mockFile = { name: "Filename", size: 12345 };
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile); 
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "/image/url");
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to push the mockFile in the dropZone manually like this

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
```

It's work for me... if you need more code just ask!

Comment: myDropzone.files.push(mockFile) is important, because function like if (this.files.length > 1) {    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);} doesn not work on page load. (function for remove first image and replace with current. For maxFiles:1)

Answer (score 0):

Mock file is not uploaded as explained here https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/418

If you want to submit the form use `myDropzone.uploadFiles([]);` in `init()`

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on("click", function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                var form = $(this).closest('#dropzone-form');
                if (form.valid() == true) { //trigger ASP.NET MVC validation
                    if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        myDropzone.processQueue();  
                    } else {                       
                        myDropzone.uploadFiles([]);
                    }                                    
                }               
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

example for U!

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //文件上传
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({
        url : "pic_upload.jsp?id=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>",
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        dictRemoveLinks : "x",
        dictCancelUpload : "x",
        maxFiles : 5,
        maxFilesize : 5,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",

        init : function() {     
            //上传成功处理函数
            this.on("success", function(file) {
                alert("修改前:"+file.name);

            });

            this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                alert("File " + file.name + "removed");
                //ajax删除数据库的文件信息
                $.ajax({    
                    type:'post',        
                    url:'pic_delete.jsp?id='+file.name ,   
                    cache:false,      
                    success:function(data){

                    }    
                });
            });


            <%
            if(null!=list){
                for(PlaceImg img:list){%>
                //add already store files on server
                var mockFile = { name: "<%=img.getId()%>", size: <%=img.getFilesize()%> };

                // Call the default addedfile event handler
                this.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

                // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
                this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "<%=img.getImgUrl()%>");
                <%}
                }%>

        }
    });
```